# Maven Shade : include only specific artifacts and exclude all the rest

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to achieve a very simple thing : Only include some artifacts in my build, while excluding everything else. I do not want to specify both include and excludes.

(Actually my problem with Maven Shade goes deeper than syntax, it is also about its logic, that puzzles me : I find the double paradigm (Inclusion + Exclusion) confusing because to me both are linked.)

I have been scratching my head for hours about this. 
Although a few examples are provided [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) in the doc, I failed to find a working syntax in my case (I keep on getting everything included whatever I tried). 

<sub>*(I find the documentation pretty light IMHO and I can't find a thorough comprehensive reference for this plugin.)*</sub>

I am sure there is a way to achieve this.

```
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>**:**</artifact>

                  <includes>
                    <include>org/apache/logging/**</include>
                  </includes>

                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>all/the/rest/**</exclude>
                  </excludes>

                </filter>
               </filters>
```

also :

what is this /path/to/artifact syntax ? Does org/apache/logging refer to artifact org.apache.logging or am I mistaken.

Comment: Since you want `**:**` why not using `artifactSet` instead of `filter`? filters are meant to fine-grain whitelist (or blacklist) individual classes from specific artifacts. (Thats why it uses the antglobs to the classes instead of the group:artifact format)

Comment: Because I did not stumble upon the following reference page until googling your suggestion: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html

Comment: @guido Could you please put your comment as an answer so i can mark it as such ? This worked : `<artifactSet>
                <includes>
                    <include>org.apache.logging.log4j:*</include>
                </includes>
              </artifactSet>`

Answer (score 3):

I used the following approach as suggested in a comment :

```
     <plugin>

         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.2.1</version>

         <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase> 
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>

            <configuration>

              #here comes the interesting part
              <artifactSet>
                <includes>
                    <include>org.apache.logging.log4j:*</include>
                </includes>
              </artifactSet>

            </configuration>

          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: exactly like that, happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this, it will include all the classes from org.apache.maven package

Sample ex:-

```
<profiles>
            <profile>
                <id>TestShadeProfile</id>
                <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.3</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <phase>package</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>shade</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                    <artifactSet>
                                     <includes>
                                      <include>org.apache.maven:* 
                                      </include>
                                     </includes>
                                    <excludes>
                                    <exclude>*:maven-core</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                   </artifactSet>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>
            </profile>
        </profiles>
```

hope it will help you

Comment: Please use most recent version of maven-shade-plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Comment: While this might work, I prefered the simpler approach suggested by @guildo in the comment section, using ArtifactSet

Comment: <artifactset> will include/exclude from final jar where <artifact> will inlcude/exclude from particular jar. this is the diff between my ans and @guildo

Comment: Interesting indeed. I'll keep that in mind, thanks.